# Types of Action Filters in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In an Interview, interviewer asked me the types of Action Filters. But i never heard or read types of Action Filters. I know , in ASP.Net MVC there are 4 filters i.e. AuthorizeFilter, ActionFilter, ResultFilter and ExceptionFilter.
But what are the types of ActionFilters. How many types of ActionFilters exist in ASP.MVC?

Comment: Maybe he means the `[POST]` and `[GET]` etc.?

Answer (score 0):

From : [Action Filtering in ASP.NET MVC Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209(v=vs.100).aspx)  , [Understanding Action Filters](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)

The ASP.NET MVC framework includes several action filters:

- OutputCache – This action filter caches the output of a controller action for a specified amount of time.
- HandleError – This action filter handles errors raised when a controller action executes.
- Authorize – This action filter enables you to restrict access to a particular user or role.

Comment: These are the types of Filters in MVC. I am asking about the types of Action Fiters.